# How to find "essential" methods to provide an interface of Ruby mixins?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, interface, implementation

The horribleness of the title of the question is what I'm trying to solve. Example:

in Ruby, Enumerable is an interface in a sense that I can implement something and document it as:

```
def myfancymethod(please_pass_me_an_Enumerable_here)
```

but on the other hand, Enumerable is a kind of amplification of the interface that has #each as one of it's methods. If I have a class

```
class Foo
  def each
    :bar
  end
end
```

For those unfamiliar with Ruby, if you mixin Enumerable module in a class, you get dozens of methods that only rely on `#each` method to provide things like `#map`, `#select`, etc.

I could say my `Foo` class is Enumerable-able or Enumerable-compatible or what? What terms describe an answer to "What does it take to be an Enumerable?", "Well you have to have #each"

Similarly, in Ruby

```
(Array.new.methods - Object.new.methods).size # 111
```

Does that mean that to fake an Array interface, I have to implement 111 methods? No way, but how to I find out what methods are the "essence" of Array. is it just `#[]`, `#[]=` and `#size`? How to make sense of it?

Comment: Is your question about the term? Or about how to find "essential" methods?

Comment: I think this would be a lot easier to answer in a language that had interfaces.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the latter would be amazing. I still don't know what "essential" ActiveRecord or Array methods are.

Comment: What does "fake an Array interface" mean in a duck-typing language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in [this feature request](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6442), which suggests some improvements to the architecture of the widely used `Hash` class.

The sad truth is *forget about it*. At this point Ruby has nothing like this. `Enumerable` and `Comparable` are about as close as it gets and their "contract" is merely a matter of documentation.

By the way, I believe `#size` is the other method that `Enumerable` can make use of, though it is optional.

Answer (score 5):

I think of the word ["contract"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Enumerable's contract, for example, is "give me `#each` and I'll give you these fancy methods".

Comment: Is there a catalog somewhere of common/existing "Contracts"? I never seen anything like that in Ruby world. I can seen now that in Java this tracking is unnecessary cause you just publish a class used like  "new Enumerable(Eachable source)" or do inheritance.

Comment: Also, "Design by Contract" is great, but it goes into the whole science of pre/post conditions/invariants etc. I'm just interested in sets of "essential" interfaces.